# Using `afterRender` hook with nested views

Tags: ember.js

[Here is the jsFiddle if you like to see code first](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/vPbM4/4/)

What I want to do is simple: execute some (actually a lot) of view layer Javascript code from jQuery and jsPlumb libraries after ALL the views in the current route have finished rendering. After getting some help from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13339048/527559) and finding that ember-latest has just been updated to include `afterRender` hook, I decided to upgrade. I now have the almighty `afterRender` hook.

All the views I am inserting into the dom have a `block` class associated with them. So the way I have been testing to see if all the views are in the dom is using `$('.block').size()` and seeing if it matches expected number.

However I am facing some issues when I try to use this hook in my application. I first tried to call the `afterRender` in the router, after the calls to `connectOutlets`. I always get only 1 block when I print out the number of blocks in dom while there should be 10.

If I put this code in `didInsertElement` of my local `block` view:

```
didInsertElement: () ->
    knob = this.$("##{@get 'knobId'}")
    name = this.$(".name")
    main = this.$(".main") #block html content will be injected into main
    knob.hide()

    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, ()->
      console.log ">> block count: ", $(".block").size()
    )
    ...
```

Then I get the following output:

```
>> block count: 1
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
>> block count: 10
```

For some reason the first iteration I only get 1 *block* in the dom and after that I get all 10. I am not sure why. But the main issue here is that if I put the hook inside `didInsertElement`, the code gets executed for an arbitrary number of views depending on data (in this example 10). However I only want to run this code once after all views have finished rendering.

Note that the view I am working with has nested data. I tried to [reproduce this on jsFiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/vPbM4/4/) but I failed in the sense that it seems to work all find and dandy on the fiddle. Maybe because my views are big and complex it is causing some synchronization issues? In any event, I think we can use the fiddle as a way to discuss a solution and I can test it locally.

One hack I tried to do to get around the issue is to schedule my code to run after 500ms delay using `Ember.run.later`. That did solve the issue on my local machine. However, using a timer to do this is very sheep dung and does not work reliably since different browsers or machines may take longer to render the views.

This is a though one to reproduce and I have already spent much time trying to find a solution. I would appreciate any help in reproducing the problem here or finding a solution.

**Edit (workaround):** Thanks to look for helping me troubleshoot this problem, and by looking at [this post about a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097401/527559), I came up with the following temporary workaround, which I put inside the router code:

```
    # Keep trying until there are two or more blocks in DOM
    blocksLoaded = ->
      console.log "blocks number ...: ", $('.block').size()
      if $('.block').size() > 1
        console.log "Yay!...we have ", $('.block').size()
        startTraversingBlocks()
      else
        Ember.run.next(this, ()->
          blocksLoaded()
        )

    blocksLoaded()
```

This outputs:

```
blockies number ...: 0
blockies number ...: 1
blockies number ...: 1
blockies number ...: 1
...
blockies number ...: 1
blockies number ...: 10
Yay!...we have 10
```

As Luke pointed out, the problem here is that my nested views are being rendered over several RunLoops. when I refresh the browser I get a different number of `blockies number ...: 1` output everytime, anywhere between 4 and 10 times during my tests.

In my opinion this is not a very good solution, but it seems to work for my use case. I feel that there is a need here for another hook that allows one to access DOM when it is guaranteed all the elements from views are accessible through jQuery selectors, but perhaps I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran this question past Kris Selden, and he said "afterRender is after the render queue is totally flushed for that run loop; I'm guessing this is over more than one loop"

The most likely possibility is that you have a record array loading. Perhaps it starts with one item and then 9 more load in later. If you rule out data loading, perhaps you have an `Ember.run.next` or `Ember.run.later` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I commented out all the other uses of `Ember.run` but I still get only 1 view. It sounds more like the first scenario you describe. The data I am using for this view is nested as I mentioned and there are arrays of views inside it. I dont think I am explicitly telling ember to render the first view individually. If we assume that it is the first scenario, can you explain a bit more what I could do to mitigate the issue?

Comment: If you know you are expecting greater than one item, you could wrap the view in a {{#if ...}} handle bars helper using a conditional property that evaluates to true when the quantity exceeds 1. We ran into a similar problem in our app because 1 item was sideloaded, and then we do a query to load the rest.

Comment: ok this sounds promising, but I am not sure if I understand well. Where would I put such condition? In the View class definition? Is this something you could show me in the fiddle I provided? In my handlebard I am nesting the view by referencing back to `this` so I am not clear how to implement what you say.

Comment: and yes I am expecting 2 or more items (or views)

Comment: Here is an update for the purpose of showing where the #if would go. http://jsfiddle.net/vPbM4/5/

Comment: thanks that looks like it may work, and I will try that i my own app when I get a chance. Right now I found this hack to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12097401/527559 and since I have a deadline tomorrow I am going to move on and come back to this issue at a later time. Thanks again for all your help Luke!