# Emberjs: Prevent back button from moving into another state

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When a state describes a view rendered in a modal/popup, we ideally want the user to only navigate away from it through offered options i.e Save or Cancel buttons.

The back button presents a real issue when you design your application with states in mind and you use modals to render views in certain states (New, Edit ...).

Is there a way to hack into the states history to prevent, when desired, landing in a state through the back button.

Comment: This is an open issue in the Ember router (see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1606)

Comment: When path changes routers are used to load a new path. You need to hack Router to solve this problem. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596733/using-afterrender-hook-with-nested-views